# VS Code extension not visible on remote server

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have developed a VS Code extension that provides statistics about remote servers in the left sidebar. The extension performs SSH requests to a list of servers, retrieves data, and displays it to the user. The extension works correctly when I open VS Code normally, but when I connect to a remote server using the Remote SSH extension, my extension is not visible in the sidebar. I have tried all combinations for `extensionKind`. My workflow is: open vscode locally, press f5 to debug, from the new window connect to a server.

I have already attempted to modify the package.json file of my extension by adding the "extensionKind" attribute like `"extensionKind": ["ui"]`, as described in the official VS Code documentation (https://code.visualstudio.com/api/advanced-topics/remote-extensions), but the extension remains invisible on the remote server.

I would like my extension to have a similar behavior to the Remote SSH extension, where it remains visible and functional even on a remote server. What additional steps or modifications do I need to undertake to ensure that my extension is visible when connected to a remote server using the Remote SSH extension?

Comment: and you want to have it run on the remote? read the doc

Comment: Of course I already did a web search. I also checked the documentation for the package.json file (https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/extension-manifest). But even if I change the extensionKind the problem remains.

Comment: copy the extension dev directory to the remote server, connect local VSC to remote and open ext dev workspace and then debug, if all works set `extensionKind` to the correct value for published extension

Comment: I can't debug on the server for security reasons. However, I have also tried to create .vsix files with the different combination of "extensionkind" on my local and then install those extensions on the remote. The extension is installed but doesn't run.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by setting `extensionKind=["ui"]` and uninstalling and reinstalling VS Code on the remote server. It appears that previously, VS Code was not activating the extension even though it was installed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).